# Accessing external array whose typedef is also defined outside

Tags: c, external

I'm writing a code (*testcode.c*) to test a set of APIs. Folder structure is as shown below.

```
/folder  
|  
|-- driver.c  
|-- driver.h  
|-- testcode.c
```

I have permission to do slight modifications to *driver.h*, but cannot modify *driver.c*.
Now *driver.c* has some very large `const` arrays defined in it which I want to access from *testcode.c*.
I would have used extern decleration in *driver.h* but array type is also defined in the *driver.c* itself.
For now I copied all of `const` arrays to *testcode.c*.

I was wondering if there is any alternate method/hack I could use here instead of copying the array definition.

Refer minimal code below:

***driver.c***

```
typedef struct{
  NAME_ENUM_e      name;
  TYPE_ENUM_e      type;
  SETTING_ENUM_e   setting;
}SETTINGS_t;

const SETTINGS_t sValueArr[LARGE_NUMBER][3] =    /* <-- I want to use this array in testcode.c */
{
   {
     {EE_NAME1,  EE_TYPE1, EE_SETTING20},
     {EE_NAME1,  EE_TYPE2, EE_SETTING30},
     {EE_NAME1,  EE_TYPE3, EE_SETTING40},
   },
    ...
    ...
   {
     {EE_NAME10,  EE_TYPE1, EE_SETTING30},
     {EE_NAME10,  EE_TYPE2, EE_SETTING20},
     {EE_NAME10,  EE_TYPE3, EE_SETTING40},
   },
}
```

***driver.h***

```
typedef enum{
    EE_NAME1,
    EE_NAME10,
}NAME_ENUM_e;

typedef enum{
    EE_TYPE1,
    EE_TYPE2,
    EE_TYPE3,
}TYPE_ENUM_e;

typedef enum{
    EE_SETTING20,
    EE_SETTING30,
    EE_SETTING40,
}SETTING_ENUM_e;
```

Comment: ? 1. Copy the struct definition to your `testcode.c` 2. Add `extern` deeclarations of these arrays in `testcode.c`. Note that if the structure definitions get out of sync, it will be a very hard bug to found. So you can write a program to preprocess the `driver.c` file to extract the definition.

Comment: ok that did work. i thought using a different typedef with `extern` will produce compile error. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there is no way to do it while maintaining type consistency without moving `typedef` into the header. Your solution of copying definitions is very fragile, because it would cause undefined behavior when definitions get out of sync.

Long answer: assuming that the authors of `driver.c` did not put `typedef` into the header is intentional, the reason they did it was to keep their constants hidden. They wanted freedom to change the number of items, the structure of the array, replace it with something completely different, or even to remove it completely.

Ideally, your code shouldn't need to access these constants at all. If your test code must rely on the constants from `driver.h`, the decision to make them private was probably a mistake.